# How do I remove the colon from this capturing group in PCRE, while still capturing correctly?

Tags: regex

Given this regex

```
^(?P<book>[\d]?\s?[\D]+)(?P<chapter>\s[\d]*)?(?P<verse>[:|\s]+[\d]*)?$
```

How do I stop the colon from being captured without messing up the "Chapter" group? If I put the colon to the left of the "Verse" group, "1 John 3" registers as

```
[
  "book" => "1 John",
  "chapter" => "",
  "verse" => "3"
]
```

But "1 John 3:2" captures as

```
[
  "book" => "1 John",
  "chapter" => "3",
  "verse" => ":2"
]
```

[Tool to Test in Realtime](http://regexr.com/398g2)

I'd like the capture to exclude the colon, because it shouldn't be the application's job to "fix" a botched regex.

### Desired Result

```
[
  "book" => "1 John",
  "chapter" => "3",
  "verse" => "2"
]
```

### Edit

Sorry, didn't realize that the link above doesn't save the text I was using. Here's a couple strings I was testing against:

```
1 John 3:12
Matthew 3
2 Peter 4:1
St John
```

Comment: Please, post the string.

Comment: My suggestion? remove it afterwards.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: It's in there, "I John 3".

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight: I know I could do that super simply, but that feels like I'm shimming my application to fix something that should be done in the regex.

Comment: I'm saying to remove it afterwards because a) regex can be pretty unreadable sometimes, so it's better to keep it as simple as possible, and b) it takes one line to remove it. One line as compared to who-knows-how-long looking at a regex when you have to go back into maintain this code trying to figure out what the hell you did.

Comment: @Goldentoa11 the example input you've posted does not contain any tags...

Comment: @alfasin: 4th line, ...`to the left of the "Verse" group, "1 John 3" registers as`

Comment: @Goldentoa11 the regex contains `<book>` - do you see such a tag in your example ?

Comment: @alfasin: Those (assuming you're referring to `?P<something>`) are named capturing groups, so that the result returned has string indices, not just numeric ones. [reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html)

Comment: @Goldentoa11 holy cr@p - my bad...

Comment: It's more a convenience thing I'm using. The regex matches the same as without `?P<whatever>`

Comment: @Goldentoa11 just move your spaces and colons outside the capture groups and use a zero or more quantifier: http://regex101.com/r/lY8hA0/1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand well what you are trying to do, you can use this pattern:

```
/^(?<book> (?:\d\h+)? [a-z]+(?:\h[a-z]+)* )
  (?:
      \h+ (?<chapter> \d+ )
      (?: : (?<verse> \d+ ) )?
  )?$
/xmi
```

[online demo](http://regex101.com/r/eC7xX3/2)

Comment: Thanks for the help! Works great. Also, really neat tool you linked to. I've always used Regexr, but that looks like it is more robust.

Comment: `regex101.com` is indeed more useful, and if you need to test split regex, you can use `regex.larsolavtorvik.com`

Comment: I was very confused because I misread that last non-capture group as a lookahead. "Wha-at, you can put capturing groups in lookaheads?!" lol

Comment: @AdamSmith: there is no lookaheads in this pattern. But you really can put a capture group in a lookahead.